# I'm looking to find a particular word in a bunch of text files and find the next word is?

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a powershell script to process a bunch of text files, find and replace certain words stored in a csv file, and then to do a number of other changes. I've done most of the script. I'm using a foreach loop, using Get-content to pipe the text file contents through a number of commands, and then I write the output from the file into a new file, using Set-content.

```
foreach($Newbug in $Bugslist){
    Write-Output "Processing Find Replace on : $Newbug"
    Get-Content $Newbug | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($item in $FindReplaceList){$_ = $_ -replace $item.FindString,     $item.ReplaceString}       
    $_ = $_ -replace "You are rec", "-- `r`nYou are rec"
    $_
    } | Set-Content $DONEPATH\modbug.tmp -Force
    $file = Get-ChildItem $Newbug
    $Newbug = $file.Name
    Rename-Item $DONEPATH\modbug.tmp $DONEPATH\$Newbug -Force
}
```

I'm stuck on adding a piece of code which finds the line in $Newbug which begins "Reporter" followed by an email address. I want to be able to delete that line entirely, but store that following email address into a variable so I can insert that email address into another line in the file when I parse it again ? I know that the word following Reporter is always an email address, so I do not need to confirm it is of the correct format.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: You should use `-match 'Reporter (.+)'` regular expression and to find Reporter line with anything after it. Then you can use basckreference to obtain the text after it.